# eclipse, generating entities from tables, re-enable "do not ask again"

Tags: eclipse

When generating entities from tables in Eclipse, I made a mistake and chose "do not ask again" flag. Now it never asks the next dialog, so I want to re-enable that question.

How can I reach that?

Answer (score 1):

It is about switching flag in settings file.

File location: `\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.ui\dialog_settings.xml`

Steps:

1. Exit the Eclipse
2. Locate file mentioned above
3. Set `dontShowOverwriteEntitesFromSchemas.warning` key to `false` in file's content
4. Open the Eclipse